# Get data from hybris platform

Tags: java, web-services, salesforce, apex, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm new in hybris and I want to know how to get data from hybris, for example we have a java application and this application wants to bring data from hybris list of product.

I know you should use a web service but I tried to find a good tutorial, but I have not found any good documentation

Comment: wiki.hybris.com is your friend. you need to get registered with them.

Comment: These is no way to answer this.

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to hybris wiki for help .Possible ways I can think of are -
1)Use hybris vjdbc jar and then you can query Hybris in a manner very similar to jdbc.
2)Use REST WS.For that you have to create a REST WS in hybris and then your application can call that WS to get the data.
3)YOU know the hybris db URL and credentials use jdbc and make a db connection and bypass hybris altogether .But it is going to be damn complex.

PS-For more information on hybris you can have a look at [HybrisHub](http://www.hybrishub.com)

Answer (score 2):

With the introduction of the Hybris WebService API, it is possible for external applications to communicate with SAP Hybris Commerce using RESTful web service calls. This can be used for performing authenticated CRUD (Create, Read, Update and Delete) operations on Models in the ServiceLayer, and for invoking commands. This further simplifies the inclusion of SAP Hybris Commerce in other software architectures. It allows them to interact with SAP Hybris Commerce with a widely adopted, extensible, and intuitive protocol.

You can create an ordinary Web service in your custom extension with webservice-nature.

**Steps to Create Custom Extension for Web Services:**

You can mark one of your own extensions as a webservice extension:

1. Create a new extension using the yempty template.
2. Add the new extension to localextensions.xml file.
3. In the command line go to the platform directory and call: ant.
4. In the command line go to the new extension directory and call ant webservice_nature -Dextname=customextension.

*local.properties*

```
################################################################################
# Global flag for an extension which will be a webservice extension in platform # 
#################################################################################
webservice.module={extensionname}
```

Such customized extensions you are able to provide any custom binaries into WEB-INF\lib folder and use them in override resources and DTOs.

Check [source](https://help.hybris.com/6.6.0/hcd/8c0267f486691014a66faf3be00ad744.html) documentation.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18953195)

Comment: Thanks for the hint, Please check the updated answer.